# What is the best way to develop shopping offers chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a requirement of developing chrome extension which will display latest offers and coupons if I visit any affiliate store like amazon, aliexpress, flipkart, myntra etc.

When I visit their website and if my extension is installed then that website will should be injected with popup having offers and coupons of that website. (I have a webservice from where i will fetch offers and coupons).

It will be something like shown in below image.
[image]

I have tried something similar this way but i'm not sure it's the right way to do.

From **Manifest.json**

```
    "content_scripts": [
        {
          "matches": ["*://*/*"],
          "js": ["jquery.js","myscript.js"],
          "css":["offers.css"]
        }
    ],
    "web_accessible_resources":[
        "offers.html",
        "offers.js"
    ]
```

**myscript.js**

```
var url = chrome.extension.getURL('offers.html');
var iframe = "<iframe src='"+url+"' id='IframeID'></iframe>";
var host = window.location.host;
var splittedHost = host.split('.');
var title = $(document).find("title").text();
if(title != ''){
    $('body').append(iframe);
}
```

**offers.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>test| Latest Offers</title>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="offers.js"></script>
</head>
<body id="bodyText">
    <h1>
        Welcome
    </h1>
    ...
</body>
</html>
```

Using This I got something like this in every page I visit:

[image]

That iframe is actually offers page and to get offers data I need host name from url. I tried getting `window.localtion.host` in offers.js injected in offers.html but I get `chrome://extension`.

Can anyone suggest me how to get host name in offers.js or is there any way I can append data in offers.html from myscripts.js? and where to call the API and how to append result in to iframe body?

Comment: I don't understand what your _actual question_ here is. You've shown working code, so what's the problem?

Comment: Hi thanks for replying,
It's actually not working code.
That iframe is actually offers page and to get offers data i need host name from url.
I tried getting window.localtion.host in offers.js injected in offers.html but i get chrome://extension.
I need url name in offers page because from url i will fetch offers data.

Comment: Also, is that best way to display that div with iframe or something else is better?

Comment: _"That iframe is actually offers page and to get offers data i need host name from url. I tried getting window.localtion.host in offers.js injected in offers.html but i get chrome://extension."_ And why is that **not actually in the question**? Please edit your question so that what you're actually asking is clear.

Comment: Ok, i will edit it but can you please provide or suggest me any solution?

Comment: A solution, by definition, solves some well-defined problem. You don't have one - yet. [How to Ask guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may be helpful here.

Comment: Is there any other forum where i can get solution??

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone suggest me how to get host name in offers.js or is there any way I can append data in offers.html from myscripts.js?

As a quick solution, if you only need the URL, you can pass it as a query parameter:

```
// myscript.js
var url = chrome.extension.getURL('offers.html?url=' + window.location.host);

// offers.js
// Using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL
var host = new URL(location.href).searchParams.get('url');
```

If you do need to extract more information from the page, you can use `postMessage` for communication with the embedded window.

```
// myscript.js
iframe.contentWindow.postMessage(message, chrome.runtime.getURL(""));

// offers.js
window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
  var message = event.data;
  /* ... */
});
```

This can be made bi-directional as well, though this is outside the question's scope.

> where to call the API and how to append result in to iframe body?

Well, in `offers.js`, and then modify the DOM of that page.

*Edit:* Apparently, this is problematic as security policies from the page leak into the iframe, blocking a call to HTTP endpoint.

- You *should* use HTTPS to begin with. It's the privacy of your users that is at stake.
- You can work around it by delegating the API call to a background page using [Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging). A background page does not have this restriction.
- ..you still should be using HTTPS. This *can be a reason for rejection* when your extension is reviewed.

Comment: Thanks you for solution,I will try ASAP. :)

Comment: I got this error while fetching data with ajax on.

jquery.js:4 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.flipkart.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://API URL'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Comment: Looks like i can not request ajax call from HTTPS to HTTP. right?
So is there any alternative of it or i will have to call API from HTTPS?

Comment: To avoid it, you can simply secure your endpoint with HTTPS? With Let's Encrypt around, it's not that hard..

Comment: No i don't have HTTPS